# can't output dialog value on bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, git, dialog

I have a dynamic menu on dialog (the items are provided from an array) but the menu is not displaying the selected option

```
gp_options=()
for i in `find ~ -type d -name .git`; do
    gp_options+=("" "$i")
done

gp_dialog=(dialog --stdout --extra-button --help-button \
--ok-label 'Access repository' \
--extra-label 'Create repository' \
--cancel-label 'Remove repository'
--help-label 'Cancel' \
--backtitle "Welcome to Git Bash `whoami`!" \
--title ' Manage repositories ' \
--menu 'Manage repositories' \
0 0 0 \
"${gp_options[@]}")

dialog --stdout --msgbox "$manage_repositories" 0 0
```

Comment: (1) What is `dialog` supposed to write on stdout? (2) Did you try tor run with set -x so that you can see whether the parameters are correct?

Comment: dialog is supposed to write the option selected by the user on the menu (gp_dialog) for example: `/home/user/.git` (and how do use set -x?)

Comment: You must have made a mistake copying your example. Is `gp_dialog` supposed to be an array, or the result of running `dialog` in which case you need `=$(...)`. What is in var `manage_repositories`?

Comment: The gp_dialog is the actual menu dialog, and you're right, i forgot to put the =$(), thank you @meuh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of research, i finally found a answer:

```
repositorios=() ; i=0
while read -r line; do
    let i=$i+1
    repositorios+=($i "$line")
done < <( find ~ -type d -name .git )

gerenciar_repositorios=$(dialog --stdout --extra-button --help-button \
--ok-label "Acessar repositório" \
--extra-label 'Criar repositório' \
--cancel-label 'Remover repositório' \
--help-label 'Cancelar' \
--backtitle "Bem vindo ao Git Bash `whoami`!" \
--title ' Gerenciar repositórios ' \
--menu 'Gerenciar repositórios' 0 0 0 \
${repositorios[@]})
```